# Element type invalid in component created by ConnectFunction

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux

I am new to React Native and I am running into the following error when using Connect function of redux.
THe error reads:

***Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it´s defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of 'ExploreScreen'. The error is located at: In ExploreScreen (created by Connect Function) in ConnectFunction (...)***

Here is the relevant code in the ExploreScreen class:

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import _getBusinessLocationMarkersAsync from '../BusinessLocations/_getBusinessLocationMarkersAsync';
import { setLocation, setFilters, setBusiness } from '../Reducer/BusinessLocationsReducer';

export class ExploreScreen extends Component {

  async componentDidMount (){
    businessx = await _getBusinessLocationMarkersAsync();
    this.props.setBusiness(businessx)
  }

  render(){
    const { filters, business } = this.props;
    const mapSpots = filters.type === 'all' ? business
      : business.filter(business => business.type === filters.type);
     
    return(
      <>
        <MapView/>
        <View>
            <Ionicons name='ios-funnel' size={24} color='red'/>
        </View>
    </>
    
    )};
}}

//redux connect
const moduleState = state => ({
  business: state.business.spots,
  filters: state.business.filters,
  location: state.business.location,
});
const moduleActions = {
  setLocation,
  setBusiness,
  setFilters,
}
export default connect (moduleState, moduleActions)(ExploreScreen);
```

i didnt get this error before I added the view with the ionicon to the render. sometimes i also get an error mentinoning a memory leak, but not all the time...
I did my best to lay this down well, but I am new to React Native so let me know if something is missing.

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing 2 exports : one on the class, one on the connect fonction. Try removing the one on the class.

From :

```
export class ExploreScreen extends Component {
```

To :

```
class ExploreScreen extends Component {
```

Comment: Thanks Anto thats a good point, although it didnt solve my problem. I also get a ''cant perform a react state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel allsubscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the ComponentWillUnmount method'' and a ''Possible unhandled promise rejection error'', if this helps narrow down the solution?

Comment: Not sure of this, but try to do `_getBusinessLocationMarkerAsync().then(res => {this.props.setBusiness(res)})`

Comment: Still same problem... Maybe it could have to do with the fact that then I use the ExploreScreen generated with connect for the navigator?